# SQL Server send automated mails once we update Email column in a table

Tags: sql-server

We have a table in SQL server, where we have a identity column Id, and a Email column.

No problem when we insert data to that table, problem is if we update the email column then SQL Server sends mail to that email id.

E.g. if we execute this query

```
Update <tableName> 
Set Email = 'abc@xyz.com' 
Where id = 1111
```

then SQL Server will send an email. How can I stop that? I can't find any triggers either.

Is there any way

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know Sql Server is sending the email (as opposed to some other process)?

Comment: I am executing the Query in SQL server, and I am receiving the mail as well

Comment: this is SOLVED  :)

Comment: How was it solved? Was it a trigger? Or some external process watching Change Tracking?

Comment: There is a JOB, which is responsible for sending mails